# Gitlab runner fail to use cache with minio

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, minio

I installed a self-hosted Gitlab using the Helm chart on a Kubernetes cluster.
Everything is working fine except one thing: the cache.

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have

```
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/
```

But when running the job I have this warning when trying to download the cache:

```
WARNING: Retrying...                                
error=Get https://minio.mydomain.com/runner-cache/gitlab-runner/project/6/default?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=xxx: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

And when uploading I have:

```
WARNING: Retrying...                                error=received: 501 Not Implemented
Uploading cache.zip to https://minio.mydomain.com/runner-cache/gitlab-runner/project/6/default 
FATAL: received: 501 Not Implemented
```

But the certificate is provided by LetsEncrypt so it's not an unknown authority. When I go on minio.mydomain.com I can see that the connection is secure

[image]

I've also check that the runner is using the right credentials and yes it is.

I'm kind of lost here. Any hints is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the CA to the image that is hosting the cache.

You can follow these instructions from this gitlab [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3371#workaround) for a workaround:

> Update the helper image to have the ca chain for the self-signed certificate trusted.
>
> ```
> FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-latest
>
> RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
>
> COPY ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
>
> RUN update-ca-certificates
>
> RUN rm /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
> ```
>
> `docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/namespace/project/tools/gitlab-runner-helper:$SOME_TAG`
>
> [Override](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#overriding-the-helper-image) the helper image used by GitLab by updating the config.toml to use the image you just build with the correct CA trusted.
>
> If you are using the helm chart you can define `KUBERNETES_HELPER_CPU_LIMIT` environment variable and define it in [`envVars`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/blob/902283d232a5b272603fdce4c11701d43b41fc78/values.yaml#L314-316)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried what you described but instead of using KUBERNETES_HELPER_CPU_LIMIT I added the custom image in the config.toml of the runner and restarted the pods but the error is still here. Maybe I'm missing something else. Still thank you for the information.